# Regex to match the date from string with where clause

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I need to get the date string i.e. **2019-01-22 15:36:141,023** from the below sample text only where the line contains **Correct** and not **Test12** words. So i should ideally get two matches(Line 3 and 5) in the below string.

Line 1: 2019-01-22 15:36:141,043: [Test][123] INFORMATION - Testing: Correct Test12 ping

Line 2: 2019-01-22 15:36:141,029: [Test][124323] INFORMATION - Testing: Wrong Test12 ping

Line 3: 2019-01-22 15:36:141,023: [Test][12554363] INFORMATION - Testing: Correct Test ping

Line 4: 2019-01-22 15:36:141,123: [Test][6761213] INFORMATION - Testing: Wrong Test12 ping

Line 5: 2019-01-22 15:36:141,093: [Test][46543123] INFORMATION - Testing: Invalid Test ping

Line 6: 2019-01-22 15:36:141,890: [Test][887] INFORMATION - Testing: Correct Test ping

I can get the date string with **(?\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}(?:,\d{3}\b)?)** but not sure how to include the other conditions. Any leads ?

Comment: Why not perform the additional checks separately? That would keep the code "clean" and the extraction regex easier to maintain.

Comment: Agree with Wiktor. However you can just append "Correct" and "Test " to your current regex. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ehm9dp/1)

Comment: You may use a regex like `\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2,}(?:,\d{3}\b)?(?=.*\r?$(?<!Test12.*)(?<=Correct.*))`, but it is not really the right way if you have access to code.

Comment: Agreed, Wiktor, I can read the contents line by line and include only the lines for the regex check where the condition matches but I was wondering if I could achieve this with a RegEx. BTW this regex only gives me one match line6

Comment: @coder89 You did not use the multiline option, add it, `(?m)` at the start of the pattern, or compile with `RegexOptions.Multiline`

Comment: You write *where the line contains Correct and not Test12 words.* - but should the check for `Correct` and `Test12` be performed *after* the date? Or can they appear anywhere on a line?

Comment: Try `\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2,}(?:,\d{3}\b)?(?!.*Test12)(?=.*Correct)` if you do not need to check for those words before the date

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Without adding extra complexity to the regex**, you could iterate over the lines in the file and perform the checks for `Test12` and `Correct` using regular string methods:

```
var results = new List<string>();
using (var sr = new StreamReader(filepath, true)) 
{
    var line = "";
    while ((line=sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (line.Contains("Correct") && !line.Contains("Test12")) 
        {
            var res = Regex.Match(line, @"\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2,}(?:,\d{3}\b)?");
            if (res.Success)
            {
                results.Add(res.Value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**With regex, i**f the words you want to check the presence/ansence of occur *after* the date use

```
\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2,}(?:,\d{3}\b)?(?!.*Test12)(?=.*Correct)
                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cd%7b4%7d-%5cd%7b2%7d-%5cd%7b2%7d%5cs%5cd%7b2%7d%3a%5cd%7b2%7d%3a%5cd%7b2%2c%7d%28%3f%3a%2c%5cd%7b3%7d%5cb%29%3f%28%3f!.*Test12%29%28%3f%3d.*Correct%29&i=2019-01-22+15%3a36%3a141%2c023%3a+%5bTest%5d%5b123%5d+INFORMATION+Testing%3a+Correct+Test12+ping%0d%0a2019-01-22+15%3a36%3a141%2c023%3a+%5bTest%5d%5b124323%5d+INFORMATION+-+Testing%3a+Wrong+Test12+ping%0d%0a2019-01-22+15%3a36%3a141%2c023%3a+%5bTest%5d%5b12554363%5d+INFORMATION+-+Testing%3a+Correct+Test+ping%0d%0a2019-01-22+15%3a36%3a141%2c023%3a+%5bTest%5d%5b6761213%5d+INFORMATION+-+Testing%3a+Wrong+Test12+ping%0d%0a2019-01-22+15%3a36%3a141%2c023%3a+%5bTest%5d%5b46543123%5d+INFORMATION+-+Testing%3a+Invalid+Test+ping%0d%0a2019-01-22+15%3a36%3a141%2c023%3a+%5bTest%5d%5b887%5d+INFORMATION+-+Testing%3a+Correct+Test+ping).

Here, `(?!.*Test12)(?=.*Correct)` are lookaheads that make sure 1) there is no `Test12` and 2) there is a substring `Correct` after any 0+ chars other than newline as many as possible to the right of the current location (that is, after the date).

If these words may occur anywhere in the string, you may use

```
(?m)\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2,}(?:,\d{3}\b)?(?=.*\r?$(?<!Test12.*)(?<=Correct.*))
                                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3fm%29%5cd%7b4%7d-%5cd%7b2%7d-%5cd%7b2%7d%5cs%5cd%7b2%7d%3a%5cd%7b2%7d%3a%5cd%7b2%2c%7d%28%3f%3a%2c%5cd%7b3%7d%5cb%29%3f%28%3f%3d.*%5cr%3f%24%28%3f%3c!Test12.*%29%28%3f%3c%3dCorrect.*%29%29&i=2019-01-22+15%3a36%3a141%2c023%3a+%5bTest%5d%5b123%5d+INFORMATION+Testing%3a+Correct+Test12+ping%0d%0a2019-01-22+15%3a36%3a141%2c023%3a+%5bTest%5d%5b124323%5d+INFORMATION+-+Testing%3a+Wrong+Test12+ping%0d%0a2019-01-22+15%3a36%3a141%2c023%3a+%5bTest%5d%5b12554363%5d+INFORMATION+-+Testing%3a+Correct+Test+ping%0d%0a2019-01-22+15%3a36%3a141%2c023%3a+%5bTest%5d%5b6761213%5d+INFORMATION+-+Testing%3a+Wrong+Test12+ping%0d%0a2019-01-22+15%3a36%3a141%2c023%3a+%5bTest%5d%5b46543123%5d+INFORMATION+-+Testing%3a+Invalid+Test+ping%0d%0a2019-01-22+15%3a36%3a141%2c023%3a+%5bTest%5d%5b887%5d+INFORMATION+-+Testing%3a+Correct+Test+ping).

Here, the `(?m)` option sets the `RegexOptions.Multiline` to *true* so that `$` could be parsed as the end of a line anchor, and the `(?=.*\r?$(?<!Test12.*)(?<=Correct.*))` positive lookahead performs the following check: it requires that there are 0+ chars up to the end of the line, and then, at the end of the line, the two checks are performed with lookbehinds: the negative lookbehind `(?<!Test12.*)` makes sure there is no `Test12` *anywhere* on a line and the positive lookbehind `(?<=Correct.*)` makes sure there is a `Correct` substring *anywhere* on a line.

The `\r?` optional CR before `$` is required due to a rather annoying fact that in the multiline mode `$` does not match before `\r`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean a match for line 3 and 6 because line 5 does not contain `Correct`.

To not contains "Test12" you could use a negative lookahead. To match "Correct" after, you could match it in your pattern and use a word boundary `\b` to prevent it being part of a larger word.

Your pattern might look like:

```
^(?!.*\bTest12\b).*?(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2,}(?:,\d{3}\b)?).*\bCorrect\b.*$
```

That will match:

- `^` Start of string
- `(?!.*\bTest12\b)` Assert what follows does not contain `Test12`
- `.*?` Match any char non greedy
- `(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2,}(?:,\d{3}\b)?)` Capture in a group the date like pattern
- `.*` Match any char 0+ times
- `\bCorrect\b` Match Correct
- `.*` Match any char 0+ times
- `$` End of the string

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%3f!.*%5cbTest12%5cb%29.*%3f%28%5cd%7b4%7d-%5cd%7b2%7d-%5cd%7b2%7d%5cs%5cd%7b2%7d%3a%5cd%7b2%7d%3a%5cd%7b2%2c%7d%28%3f%3a%2c%5cd%7b3%7d%5cb%29%3f%29.*%5cbCorrect%5cb.*%24&i=Line+1%3a+2019-01-22+15%3a36%3a141%2c023%3a+%5bTest%5d%5b123%5d+INFORMATION+-+Testing%3a+Correct+Test12+ping%0d%0a%0d%0aLine+2%3a+2019-01-22+15%3a36%3a141%2c023%3a+%5bTest%5d%5b124323%5d+INFORMATION+-+Testing%3a+Wrong+Test12+ping%0d%0a%0d%0aLine+3%3a+2019-01-22+15%3a36%3a141%2c023%3a+%5bTest%5d%5b12554363%5d+INFORMATION+-+Testing%3a+Correct+Test+ping%0d%0a%0d%0aLine+4%3a+2019-01-22+15%3a36%3a141%2c023%3a+%5bTest%5d%5b6761213%5d+INFORMATION+-+Testing%3a+Wrong+Test12+ping%0d%0a%0d%0aLine+5%3a+2019-01-22+15%3a36%3a141%2c023%3a+%5bTest%5d%5b46543123%5d+INFORMATION+-+Testing%3a+Invalid+Test+ping%0d%0a%0d%0aLine+6%3a+2019-01-22+15%3a36%3a141%2c023%3a+%5bTest%5d%5b887%5d+INFORMATION+-+Testing%3a+Correct+Test+ping&o=m) | [C# demo](https://ideone.com/OVPyep)

**Note**

Should this part `(?:,\d{3}\b)?` also match a digit before the comma like `(?:\d,\d{3}\b)?` looking at the example data?

Comment: Thanks @The Fourth bird brilliant (it was a typo I meant Line 3 and 6), this gives me complete line what if I need only the date string i.e. 2019-01-22 15:36:141,023

Comment: The get the date part only you could use a capturing group. In the pattern, turn `(?:` to `(` I have updated my answer.

Comment: @coder89 There is one thing about this approach: `Correct` must follow the date for the match to be found. It is most likely what you need, but you should actually clarify that requirement in your question.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You could post an answer, I will upvote it.

Comment: @Wikto my apologies if the question was not clear, your solution works like a charm.

Comment: @The Fourth bird still with the updated regex I not able to get only the date string

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way without Regex.  The Date does not look correct.  I think the comma is in wrong location so I fixed it.

```
            DateTime today = DateTime.Parse("2019-01-22 15:36:14");
            string input =
                "2019-01-22 15:36:14,1023: [Test][123] INFORMATION - Testing: Correct Test12 ping\n" +
                "2019-01-22 15:36:14,1023: [Test][124323] INFORMATION - Testing: Wrong Test12 ping\n" +
                "2019-01-22 15:36:14,1023: [Test][12554363] INFORMATION - Testing: Correct Test ping\n" +
                "2019-01-22 15:36:14,1023: [Test][6761213] INFORMATION - Testing: Wrong Test12 ping\n" +
                "2019-01-22 15:36:14,1023: [Test][46543123] INFORMATION - Testing: Invalid Test ping\n" +
                "2019-01-22 15:36:14,1023: [Test][887] INFORMATION - Testing: Correct Test ping";

            StringReader reader = new StringReader(input);
            string line = "";

            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] splitDate = line.Split(new string[] { ": [Test]" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(splitDate[0].Replace(",","."), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.FFFF", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                string[] splitTest = splitDate[1].Split(new char[] { ':' });

                if ((date.Date == today.Date) && splitTest[1].Contains("Correct") && !splitTest[1].Contains("Test12"))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(line);
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
```